# Precompiling a single file using Aspnet_compiler (or another way)

Tags: asp.net

Is there a way to precompile only a file of choice in a web site (using fixed names), instead of the whole site? e.g. : If I have a user control `MyUserControl.ascx`, only precompile this file?

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can compile .ascx files. They can be complied into dll files and can be referenced into your project.

for that you need to put the ascx and its cs file in a new web project, and complile it into a dll using Microsoft Web Deployment Tool (if I remember correctly).